# kafka connect Skipping fetch for partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have standalone confluent server that worked fine  until suddenly connect stooped to consume records .

I enabled  trace on connect and this is the debug output .

`DEBUG Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition connect-offsets-10 at offset 0 to node 10.1.*.*:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:787)`

I did some research and found out that it`s can be  related to [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread).

I try to reconfigure server proporties with those values but i got same result.

```
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
session.timeout.ms=10000
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
```

Now the connect service is in deadlock state and unable to consume records.

Answer (score 1):

please set max.poll.records to minimal value and it will solve your problem.

If polled data in an batch is taking more time than session timeout , re balancing will be triggered and same set of data is read over and over again.

Comment: Id set max.poll.records=1 
in the server prop , and in the scheme prop .
same result

Comment: can you explain more about the operation ?
how much time it takes to process 1 polled record ?
what this connector is doing ?

Comment: Manjeet, your suggestion did not work for me either. The consumer indefinitely shows - Skipping fetch for partition <TOPIC-PARTITION> because there is an in-flight request to <BROKER_HOST>:9092 (id: 41 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)